# HTML Video only Appears on Window Resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, video

I am trying to use the [vide.js](http://vodkabears.github.io/vide/) jQuery extension to add a video background to one of my divs. The code for the video div is as follows:

```
<div id="header" data-vide-bg="mp4: graphics/videos/identity.mp4, webm: graphics/videos/identity.webm, ogv: graphics/videos/identity.ogv, poster: graphics/videos/equations.png" data-vide-options="posterType: 'detect', loop: true, muted: true, position: 0% 0%">
```

It works sometimes, but if the browser cache is cleared and the page is refreshed (ctrl/cmd + shift + R in Chrome), the video does not show up until the browser window is resized.

I have also tried using jQuery to add the video to the div programmatically, to no avail.

You can see the issue live at [this address](http://h2micro.com/about.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i can see, `<video>` element is not picking its height properly..
settings styles in css to height: 100% will fix the problem

Comment: This was the issue. However, it appears that the problematic values are added by some of the vide.js code, so they appear inline. The only way to fix the problem was to add `!important` flags to the CSS.